# Microservices resource management

Tags: java, spring, architecture, microservices

Assume we have a group microsericervices (each service has its own DB ). Our clients are other companies. Each client wants to have his own database.

In this case we have many databases for each service. Is exist best practice for managemnt resources?

I think that all services can be stateless. And any company (our client) must have its own config with resources description. Example: DB, files storage and etc.

Calling any serivce must activate the resource context. And all next services must work using this context.

Example. 
Someone open in his browser site: clientCompany.com.
Our first service (example AuthenticationService) check this config and found host name "clientCompany.com" in section "hosts". 
Then it activate this context and whole chain of services use storage, DB and other resources from this context.

Resource config:

```
[  
   {  
      "contextName":"ClientCompanyName",
      "hosts":[  
         "clientCompany.com",
         "client-company.com"
      ],
      "storage":{  
         "path":"/mnt/ClientCompanyName"
      },
      .....
   },
   .....
]
```

Is this a good practice?
I'm interested in the possibilities of creating such a system using Java and Spring?
Please share links to sources and tools for implementing this task.
And tell what do you think about such implementation?

Comment: I think you are referring to PaaS. It's too broad to be discussed.

Comment: Well, you want to make sure however you determine Tenant, you can't have somebody just start trying values to see what sticks.  We put TenantId (a GUID) into our JWT Access Token which gets passed to any service being called.  We further pass TenantId in request headers when making calls between UI and services.  That lets us validate the user has access to the specific Tenant on every request.

Comment: @MikahBarnett thank you! I think this is true way!

Comment: Sure @Vladimir, added a more detailed answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to keep your TenantID's out of "public" view, so we integrated Tenant assignment into our Authorization process.

Here's how it works for us:

- A `TenantService` manages the list of all available Tenants and generates integration events when they are added/removed/changed, etc.  Each `Tenant` has both an `Id` `GUID` and an `Abbreviation` `nvarchar(5)`- more on that later
- We use OIDC between our applications and our Identity Provider (IdP) and then Bearer Tokens for all microservices
- When new Users are added to the system, at least one Tenant must be specified and this gets pushed into our IdP as Role(s) for that User
- Our Roles are in the format `tenant_abbreviation.role_name` so that the application can read roles and know what tenant they apply to.  In our case, one User might have access to more than 1 Tenant with different roles in each.
- On login, the application requests and receives a `JWT Access Token` containing user claims - this JWT is required to access all other services.  So, when a microservice gets a JWT (which it validates), it knows the UserId as well as any/all Permissions they can access per Tenant.
- When an approved application makes a call to a microservice, along with the JWT it passes the current context `TenantId` in the header so we can compare Claims vs. current Tenant - if they don't match it's a problem in the application

The downside of the system is lots of Roles/Permissions to manage, but we've automated that and, at least in our case (we use Auth0.com), even with thousands of Tenants our IdP will still handle it with no problem.  Even if our tooling slows down a little, per-tenant will still be performant.

The upsides are it's quite secure, with minimal tooling to handle the workload on the IdP it's easy to manage and track, and every service gets good, granular Authorization/context information.  It also allows a lot of flexibility to mix/match Users between Tenants (if necessary) and/or separate permissions per tenant.